# Coordinates after point multiplication not in elliptic curve.

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

When calculating $2P$ where $P = (7, 11)$ on the elliptic curve E: $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1 \mod 23$.

I get $$ \lambda = \frac{3 * 49 + 1}{2 * 22} = \frac{74}{11} \mod \ 23 = 10.$$

Then when I calculate $ x_3 = \lambda^2 - 2 * x_1 = (10^2 - 14) \mod \ 23 = 17$.

and $ y_3 = -y_1 + \lambda \ (x_1 - x_3) = (-11 + 10 \ (7 - 17)) \mod \ 23 = 4$

The calculated coordinates for 2P turned out to be (17, 4), which does not seem to lie on the elliptic curve. I would appreciate any insights into what might be the problem with this calculation.

Comment: You made an arithmetic mistake for the slope $\lambda$. $11^{-1} \equiv -2 \bmod{23}$, so $74/11 \equiv 5 \cdot (-2) = -10 \equiv 13 \bmod{23}$.

Answer (score 3):

You made an arithmetic mistake for the slope $$. Since $11^{−1}≡−2 \bmod{23}$, then $74/11≡5⋅(−2)=−10≡13 \bmod{23}$.